# Creating a 2-dimensional array with different sizes within a loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, c++17

### The problem

I have an array of `int`'s which vary in value called `sizes`. I want to create a 2d array (called `arr`) where the first dimension size is the length of the `sizes` array, and the second dimension's size is the value of the integer at that index. I hope the following code makes it easier to understand my question.

```
    int sizes[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    // What I need is an array with this shape
    {
        {0},                  // arr[0]
        { 0, 0 },             // arr[1]
        { 0, 0, 0 },          // arr[2]
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 }        // arr[3]
    };
```

My actual code, the sizes array is larger, so I would like to avoid lots of repeating lines of code if that is possible.

### My attempts

I am new to `C++`, but I have read about `constexpr`. I think I can create a function to return this array, but I have yet to get this to work.

I also think I can loop over the `sizes` array, and for each `int`, create an array with that size, but I can't then assign it to `arr`.

Comment: Please use `std::vector` instead of arrays, it's much easier.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. At the time of writing, I understood that vector indexing was slower than array indexing. It seems that I was wrong, and the performance is equal when indexing a pointer object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ doesn't support jagged 2d arrays.  A 2d array needs to have a size of `N x M` where `N` and `M` are both greater than zero.

Instead of using a 2d array, you can use a 2d vector to get this behavior like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> table;
for (auto size : sizes)
    table.push_back(std::vector<int>(size));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did think of using vectors however, and correct me if I am wrong, but isn't indexing from an array quicker than from a vector? I need to squeeze as much performance out of my code as I can.

Comment: @Kieran With compiler optimizations turned on, accessing a vector and accessing an array should have the same performance.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. I will research more into it then.

Comment: @Kieran Some intro reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740020/c-stl-array-vs-vector-raw-element-accessing-performance